# connection to postgresql; From ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 OR ArcGIS for Server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, postgresql, connection

As it is mentioned in [**ArcGIS Resources**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002p0000003q000000) "PostgreSQL client libraries are required on the ArcGIS **client application** from which you will connect to the database".

My questions are:

1. by ArcGIS client applications, they mean e.g. **ArcGIS for Desktop version 10.1**?
2. Can **ArcGIS for server 10.1** have a direct connection to e.g. Postgresql? and if **NO** why there is **pg_client_linux64**?

Are we supposed to put the client libraries in both bin directories of ArcGIS for Desktop and ArcGIS for server (on Centos)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
    a.  [See ESRI help configuring one machine arcgis for server (Linux)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Configuring_a_one_machine_deployment/01550000048p000000/).
    b.   [See also database connections in arcgis desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002p00000036000000) for specific Postgres instructions
3. Yes  [see ESRI help setting up a connection in PostgreSQL.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002p0000003q000000)
        You would need to connect from desktop and copy the connection file to the server.
    a.  You also need to register the database with arcgis for server.
        [See ESRI help registering the database with th server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/About_registering_your_data_with_the_server/0155000004zz000000/)

Comment: Thank you Brad. by Registering the database with arcgis for server, they meant basically ArcGIS for server and ArcGIS for Desktop have access to e.g. postgresql database?  I thought only ArcGIS for Dsktop has access to database and we need to add another database on the server so that we can lets say make interactive maps